# Datetime format not working. How to use it with Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, datetime-format

Im working in Laravel....

I have made an API integration were I need to handle some input data. One of the date input is a date format. But I just can't figure out how to output the data and save it into my database.

```
$d = $item->fields['date']->values;
$dt = $d['start'];
```

When I return a `dd($dt)` the output is

```
DateTime @1554076800 {#1106 ▼
  date: 2019-04-01 00:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
}
```

So how can I save the `2019-04-01` into a variable?

I use Laravel and tried with different solutions, but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$dt` is a `DateTime` object, you should just be able to call the `format` method.

For example:

```php
if ($d = $item->fields['date']) {
    $dt = $d->values['start']->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Ive tried that, but I get this error "Trying to get property 'values' of non-object"

Comment: Yes. In a foreach loop

Comment: Then I would imagine for one of the iterations `$item->fields['date']` is not a DateTime object. As it is failing on that line. Add a conditional statement before to make sure it actually exists. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Just simply check that it exists before calling the relevant methods, as I have put in the answer.